# microservices vs standalone self hosted service vs executable jar

Tags: java, microservices

From the definition I read, microservice architecture is a method of developing software applications as a suite of independently deployable, small, modular services in which each service runs a unique process and communicates through a well-defined, lightweight mechanism to serve a business goal.
In that case, if I partition my system and create my unique processes as an executable jar or a standalone self-hosted service, will that be considered as a microservice?

Comment: The definition isn't set in stone anyway and does it really matter ? microservice is an architectural pholosophy, aiming at making smaller pieces, easier to deploy/maintain.  I'd say the way the services are ran is the LEAST important characteristic.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices#Philosophy + https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html + https://martinfowler.com/microservices/#what

Comment: If your services are completely stateless then maybe yes. Usually they are recommended to be in some kind of container so that they are completely separated (mutually exclusive) in terms of system and user processes (as well as data) and you can destroy and recreate and scale on demand via some auto/configured controller mechanism.